# Sorting MySQL Table to use on Data Table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

I have a table of `Topics`, that I use in a Laravel data table.

Normally, the rows are sorted by ID, but I need to give the user the possibility to re-order the rows manually by dragging them.

**New topics are created with the position 0**.

If the user re-orders a row, the Data Table index position is saved (in the **position** field).

Now I just need a query that gets me the list of `Topics` sorted.

Imagine I have the following `Topics`:

```
+----+----------+
| Id | Position |
+----+----------+
| 1  | 2        | 
| 2  | 0        |
| 3  | 1        |
| 4  | 0        |
+----+----------+
```

The query should return:

```
+----+----------+
| Id | Position |
+----+----------+
| 1  | 0        | 
| 3  | 1        |
| 2  | 2        |
| 4  | 0        |
+----+----------+
```

Position needs to match the row index, so the only possible results are **1-3-2-4** or **4-3-1-2**, but I need the first one because **it should be ordered by id, the only constraint is if it has a position** defined.

Comment: Why not 4-3-2-1?

Comment: so what the problem? Just use order by your position field orderBy('position'). You can use the second sort by your id. $queryBuilder->orderBy('position')->orderBy('id')

Comment: That won't work because it will either order with the positions = 0's first if ASC or with the positions != 0 first if DESC

Comment: your _1-3-2-4 or 4-3-1-2_ make no sense at all. 1-3-2-4 ok. But not  4-3-1-2